# Is it possible to highlight only match_phrase query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bool query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "type": [
              "bill",
              "press release"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "health"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "policy_content": {}
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "publishdate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

User is searching for keyword "health" and the keyword gets highlighted but 'bill' and 'press release' also gets highlighted which I don't want.
How should I address this problem?

Comment: Did you have any luck with highlight_query?

Comment: Yes @eemp, It worked perfectly. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the query to use for highlights via [highlight_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query).

So you can take advantage of that by updating the highlight aspect of your query to something like this:

```
"highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
        "policy_content" : {
            "highlight_query" : {
                "match_phrase" : {
                    "policy_content" : "health"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```